# Google Earth Engine - Sentinel 5P SO2

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

I am trying to analyze the emissions of SO2 in the proximity of volcanoes (before, during, and after an eruption). I am just starting my journey with Google Earth Engine.

I started by defining my collection, the period, my geometry and then filtering out negative values.

```
var so2_s5p = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2")
          .filterDate('2021-10-10', '2021-10-14')
          .select('SO2_column_number_density')
          .filterBounds(geometry)
          .map(function(image) {
            return image.updateMask(image.gte(0))})
```

In order to have some results that are meaningful in relation to the research papers I found, I am trying to convert from mol/m2 to tons.

```
var so2_tons = so2_s5p.map(function (image) {
  return image.multiply(0.000064).copyProperties(image).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});
```

In order to preserve the property of time, I am copying `system:time_start` from the source to the newly created image, which should have the value expressed in tons.

Supposing all is good until now, I want to display the values on the map and to print a chart in Console.

```
var band_viz = {
  min: 1,
  max: 2,
  palette: ['#003049', '#669bbc', '#fdf0d5', '#c1121f', '#780000']
};

Map.addLayer(so2_tons.mean(), band_viz, 'S5P SO2');

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: so2_tons, 
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 30
});

var options = { 
  title: 'SO2 over time', 
  hAxis: { title: 'time' },
  vAxis: { title: 'SO2' },
  series: {
    0: { color: 'green' }
  }
};

chart = chart.setOptions(options);
print(chart); // Put it in the console
```

Now, if I inspect a point near my area of interest (AoI), I get a value of approximately 2. But in my chart on Y-axis I have values in the range 0 - 0.00000075.
I gather that my conversion may be incorrect. Or maybe my scale is incorrect? But why is the inspection returning values which seem okay?

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Flidiabaciu97%2FMonitoring-Volcanoes_Sentinel-5P%3AJapan_SO2_tones) is the link to my notebook.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Note that we are not a discussion forum and instead use a Focused question/Best answer model. It seems as if you have one issue here, but the exact problem is masked by multiple question marks in a bulleted list. Please [Edit] the Question to improve the focus.

Comment: Hello @Vince. Thanks for the feedback. I removed the bulleted list and I hope now it's okay

Comment: From what I see, everything is in order and the mean values when inspecting the image are within the chart range (the range values within "e-8" seem logical too, as what one would expect after you multiply by 0.000064). Can you double check there is no "e-8" to the right end of the mean values digits you are describing as approximately 2?
PS. I believe the conversion you are after would use 46g instead of 64g, you may check this  https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19444/how-to-convert-mol-m2-to-total-mass-e-g-gram-kg-etc?newreg=9ec0b016187845aea2f37df05029ae29

Comment: @Es_a 64 is molecular weight of SO2. 46 is for NO2 so,  0.000064 factor for ton/m2 of SO2 is right.

Comment: @xunilk That's right 64g for SO2, thanks